# Why doesn't mc:Ignorable work for the Password property? And what can I do about it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have got this XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="Log in" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="192" Width="512" mc:Ignorable="ignore d">
    ...
    <PasswordBox VerticalAlignment="Center" ignore:Password="Correct horse battery stapler" />
    ...
</Window>
```

Now, when I run the code, it shows a pre-filled password box at run-time.

My understanding was that `mc:Ignorable="ignore d"` would make sure that properties starting with `d:` and `ignore:` would get ignored, and indeed it works for `d:DataContext`.

So why doesn't it work for `ignore:Password` and what can I do to make a mock password show up at design-time, but an empty password box at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says this:

> ... If that attribute could not be resolved to an underlying type or programming construct, then that element is ignored.

The implication seems to be that `Ignorable` is only used to prevent the XAML parser raising any errors.  It's Ignore**able** not Ignore. In this case, there is a very real property called `Password` in that namespace that won't raise any issues.

Your `DataContext` example sets a `DataContext` attribute in the *blend* namespace, not the actual `DataContext` in the WPF namespace.  The tooling uses that at design time, but it is ignored at runtime (if you take `d` out of ignorable, it will actually generate an error if you use `d:DataContext`).

Setting the Password at design time is a bit tricky as you can't bind to `Password` as it's not a dependency property (with good reason!).  The only solution I can think of is to use an attached property that only sets the value at design time:

```
public static class PasswordHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DesignPasswordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DesignPassword",
        typeof(string), typeof(PasswordHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnDesignPasswordPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetDesignPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(DesignPasswordProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetDesignPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (string)dp.GetValue(DesignPasswordProperty);
    }

    private static void OnDesignPasswordPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(sender))
        {
            var passwordBox = (PasswordBox)sender;
            passwordBox.Password = (string)e.NewValue;               
        }            
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<PasswordBox ap:PasswordHelper.DesignPassword="Correct horse battery stapler" />
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit disappointing, but in line with my general feeling that WPF is not a finished product. (And never will be, given that Microsoft has put WPF as good as on ice.) But your answer will help me get on with my life. :-)